# firebase security rules when writing and reading from non authenticated server

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

im making firebase write calls from my next js api route backend. i want to add security rules that only let you write and read in docs of your uid, but when im writing from the backend, auth is null becasue you are signed in on the frontend not the backend. What do i do? im sure this is a common problem. I have seen that you can deny all read/write in your rules and use the admin SDK in backend to do reads/writes, but all my code is already using setDoc, getDoc, etc and I don't want to change it all

Comment: Security rules never apply to code running on backends.  They only apply to web and mobile client code, typically using Firebase Authentication to know who is making the query.  There are no workarounds to this. Your backend code needs to make a decision if the query is allowed for the person making the request.